# Android no sound in plugged-in loudspeaker?

Tags: audio, youtube

I have a Samsung Android tablet with an external loudspeaker plugged into the sound jack socket. However, the tablet keeps speaking in Youtube   throuh its own internal loudspeaker (quiet-murmurer I would call it).

I checked that the external loudspeaker works OK with a phone and the jack is firmly inserted and the volume control is at the maximum (anyway, the sound does come from the internal quiet-murmurer). Can this be an Android configuration problem ? What else can I check ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just rebooting the tablet helped.